# Can I write OS-independent code that uses keypress (or keydown) events without delay?

Tags: c++, keypress, ncurses, keydown

I'm developing a game with C++ that runs on a terminal.

I have to know what key the user pressed (or held down) in a loop without waiting for the user to press the next key.

I searched about this problem, and I found the `GetAsyncKeyState()` function for Win32 and the ncurses library for Linux.

But I'm curious, is there any way to write C++ code that works on both operating systems?

Is there any way in C++ to use keypress (or keydown) events without waiting for user input, excluding OS-dependent functions or libraries?

Please don't tell me to use `_getch()` or `cin.get()`. I don't want to wait until the user inputs a new character.

Comment: `ncurses` is available for windows as well.

Comment: (Summary of the original question's answers - there's no "standard" way of doing it, but there are libraries available)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ oh I didn't know that. I known as ncurses only works on POSIX... thank you!

Comment: @SamBob Thank you! Your comment helps me a lot:)

Comment: @Nagi `curses` worked only on POSIX, where as `ncurses` or the New Curses was ported to many systems.